# calling prepareInterstitialAds multiple times

Tags: ios, iad, interstitial

What happens if I cal `UIViewController.prepareInterstitialAds()` multiple times. I am thinking of calling this method repedeately every 30s. Is this wrong? Is this semiwrong, or is it just useless? Any help is appreciated

Comment: Why would you call it on a timer? Wouldn't you just call it after you've shown and dismissed an ad?

Comment: that 30s period is actually time between each ad is shown. When I was testing I saw that the interstitial ad doesn't get shown each time it need ti be shown, although the time between is 30s. I was thinking that interstitial ads need more than 30s to load  so perhaps repeated use of prepareInterstitialAds() would solve that problem

Comment: Unfortunately the docs are out of date, so it's hard to get a definite answer. But from my experience, and from what info I've managed to find, there seems to be a 2-3 minute enforced wait period between iAd interstitial requests. So you won't be able to get a new ad every 30 seconds. A workaround would be to use other ad networks.